# bot framework remove cardaction

Tags: c#, telegram, botframework, microsoft-skype-bot

I am using Bot Framework (Version 3.0, ASP.NET Bot Framework template) for one of my chatbot and using HeroCard & CardAction to get user's feedback. I have below issues:

1. CardAction translated into inline keyboard on Telegram channel. That works fine and remain available to user to act mutiple time in chat area. How can I remove buttons from chat area once user has taken action using that button?
2. Can I translate CardAction into reply keyboard (reply_markup) rather than inline markup?
3. CardAction are working fine with Telegram but not working in Skype. Skype is showing them as external media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bot Framework doesn't directly support Telegram's reply keyboard feature, but you can still send it via the message's channelData field. ChannelData is for sending channel-specific messages that aren't directly surfaced in the Bot Framework. In BotBuilder/NodeJS, this field is set using the message.sourceEvent method:

Example (untested):

```
var msg = new builder.Message(session);
msg.sourceEvent({
    telegram: {
        method: "sendMessage",
        parameters: {
            text: "This is a reply keyboard",
            parse_mode: "Markdown",
            reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
                "keyboard": [
                    [{ text: "1" }, { text: "2" }, { text: "3" }],
                    [{ text: "4" }, { text: "5" }, { text: "6" }],
                    [{ text: "7" }, { text: "8" }, { text: "9" }],
                    [{ text: "*" }, { text: "0" }, { text: "#" }]
                ]
            })
        }
    }
});
session.send(msg);
```

channelData field documentation: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/channels.html